Axler Theorem 5.33: Understanding assumption WLOG
Theorem 5.33 in Axler's book is ($\mathcal{L}(V)$ denotes the set of linear map $V \to V$):

Suppose $\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{R}$ and $V$ is finite-dimensional. Suppose also $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ with $b^2 < 4c$. Then $\dim \text{null}(T^2 + bT + cI)$ is an even number.

He first comments that $\text{null}(T^2 + bT + cI)$ is invariant under $T$, which I'm ok with. The next line is what I cannot follow. He says:

By replacing $V$ with $\text{null}(T^2 + bT + cI)$ and replacing $T$ with $T$ restricted to $\text{null}(T^2 + bT + cI)$, we can assume that $T^2 + bT + cI = 0$.

I don't understand why we're allowed to do this. I believe any type of assumption without loss of generality is made because the proof in some way reduces to this simpler case, but I am not able to figure out why this is so since $V$ is an arbitrary finite-dimensional vector space.

null$(T^2+bT+cI)$ is a subspace of $V$.

Let $W:=\ker(T^2+bT+cI)\le V$. You know $T(W)\le W$, so that $T|_W:W\to W$ makes sense i.e. $T|_W\in\mathcal{L}(W)$. Moreover, within $W$, $W':=\ker(T|_W^2+bT|_W+cI)$  obviously has $W'=W$. On $W$, $T^2+bT+cI=0$, by definition; now, if the theorem was proven in the special case Axler mentions, then we would know $\dim W'$ is even. But $W'=W$ and $\dim W$ being even is exactly the thing we want to show, so there is no loss.
